# Is dot-sourcing a bad thing when used in a shared environment?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm running into an issue where my PowerShell scripts just stop running. No errors or failures reported.

Basic setup looks like this:

```
c:\pss\a.ps1
c:\pss\b.ps1
c:\pss\functions.ps1
```

The `functions.ps1` file holds functions that insert, update, or delete data in SQL tables.

Both `a.ps1` and `b.ps1` use dot-sourcing to call functions in `functions.ps1`.

If I run both `a.ps1` and `b.ps1` at the same time, they run, but they never fully complete their work.

I'm running PowerShell v2.

Comment: "If I run both a.ps1 and b.ps1 at the same time, they run, but they never fully complete their work." - How are you executing them? With scheduled tasks? Two `powershell.exe` prompts started manually?

Comment: Opening two ISE sessions.

Comment: dot sourcing the same script into two different sessions shouldn't be a problem. I would suspect shared resource use in `function.ps1`, ie. a function that both `a.ps1` and `b.ps1` use that attempt to access or write to the same table, causing a deadlock. What is the contents of the 3 scripts?

Comment: "file holds functions" -> In my opinion it's better to rename `functions.ps1` to `functions.psm1` and add the line `import-module functions.psm1` to a.ps1 and b.ps1 and then just use functions by its name.

Comment: @n01d Using a module would be more elegant, but shouldn't have an effect on the problem described in the question. I agree with Mathias that `a.ps1` and `b.ps1` are probably causing a deadlock when being run in parallel.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers agreed. Module is just to exclude dot-sourcing from error checklist.